# Initializing a Double object with a primitive double value

Tags: java, autoboxing

What is happening when a java.lang.Double object is initialized without using a call to the constructor but instead using a primitive?  It appears to work but I'm not quite sure why.  Is there some kind of implicit conversion going on with the compiler?  This is using Java 5.

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double d = 5.1;

        System.out.println(d.toString());

    }

}
```

Comment: Now knowing that it's called autoboxing you can find a lot of [interesting articles in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+autoboxing) :)

Comment: Autboxing, that's what I was looking for.  Thanks SO!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is called [Autoboxing](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) which is a feature that was added in Java 5.  It will automatically convert between primitive types and the wrapper types such as `double` (the primitive) and `java.lang.Double` (the object wrapper).  The java compiler automatically transforms the line:

```
Double d = 5.1;
```

into:

```
Double d = Double.valueOf(5.1);
```

Answer (score 5):

It is called [AutoBoxing](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)

> Autoboxing and Auto-Unboxing of
>   Primitive Types Converting between
>   primitive types, like int, boolean,
>   and their equivalent Object-based
>   counterparts like Integer and Boolean,
>   can require unnecessary amounts of
>   extra coding, especially if the
>   conversion is only needed for a method
>   call to the Collections API, for
>   example.
>
> The autoboxing and auto-unboxing of
>   Java primitives produces code that is
>   more concise and easier to follow. In
>   the next example an int is being
>   stored and then retrieved from an
>   ArrayList. The 5.0 version leaves the
>   conversion required to transition to
>   an Integer and back to the compiler.

**Before**

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  list.add(0, new Integer(42)); 
  int total = (list.get(0)).intValue();
```

**After**

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  list.add(0, 42);
  int total = list.get(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's called [autoboxing](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+autoboxing).